# Aligning an ArrayList of Strings into a (custom)Box won't get in proper position

Tags: java, fonts, position, graphics2d

I've got a little problem with aligning a group of Strings to the bottom of a box in Java.

> NOTE: the `Box` class I'm using is not a default > ***javax.Swing*** box! It's a simple costum box with a x, y position, and with a width and height!

## What do I currently have?

- A `Message` class which can be individually aligned by my `Allign` class.
- A `MessageList` object containing an ArrayList of `Message` objects which can be aligned together with the `Allign` class.
- A `Box` object that contains the position and dimension of the box. The `Allign` class uses this box to align the objects in.
- The `Allign` class that can align different types of Objects, and use a `Box` object to align in.

## How does my code should work:

*(code snippets further down the page)*

The `Message` object can use different `Font` settings. The `Allign` class can align these `Message`s objects. The `Message` class contains a method called `obtainFontDimension()`, which gets the bounds of the object's String in the preferred `Font` settings. When we want to apply an alignment to a `Message` object, I create a `Box` object which contains the x,y position and the width and height. By calling `Allign.applyAllignment(params)` the calculations will be applied to align the `Message` object in the `Box`, and the `Message`'s dx, dy (drawing x, y positions) will be set.

Till here it works fine.

Now I create a `MessageList` object and add some (`Message` objects to it. When applying an alignment to this, it will run through the `Message` objects it contains, and will call the `obtainFontDimensions()` on them. The height of these Strings will be summed, and results into a total height (`int listHeight`) of the Strings together. To get the drawing position of each `Message` object, we take the y-position of the `Box` where we want to align in. First we remove the `listHeight` of the `Box`'s y position:

[image: The pre-positioning before alligning to the bottom]

Now we got the offset of the first String. When the bottom alignment is being applied, it just adds the height of the `Box` to the offset. Finally, the offset is set for the next `Message` object by adding the current `Message` object height to te offset. Time for the next iteration, till the ArrayList has been fully calculated. This should result in the following:

[image: positioning the strings to position as it should be]

## What is going wrong?

When applying an alignment to a `MessageList` object, some Strings touch eachother perfectly (see circle B on image), and some keep some pixels more distance then others (see circle A1, A2 on image). And next to that, there remains an unexpected padding on the bottom (see circle C on image).

[image]

## What have I attempted so far?

- First I've been checking the height of the Strings, which all seem to be correct. So the `obtainFontDimensions()` method seems to be working fine.
- Drawing the concept on paper, and attempt to recalculate the procedure, which should get me the correct position of the Strings. For example:

    - `Box`: x=80, y=80, width=100, height=100
    - `MessageList` with 3 `Messages`, which have a height of 0=10, 1=10, 2=20. Total height of these Strings is 40 pixels.
    - Before actually alligning, the position of the first String becomes box.y-listHeight, which is 40.
    - When actually alligning to the bottom, the the offset becomes 40+100=140.
    - The offset for the second String will be calculated: 140+20(current message's height)=160.
    - This repeats for the third string, which is is 160+10 = 170.
    - That means, that the bottom line of the final string is on 170+10 = 180, which equals the bottom of the `Box`'s bottom.

  Your suggestion...?

## Code snippets

(only important parts)

```
public class Window()
{
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
    {
        Box contentBox = new Box(100, 100, 300, 300);
        Message loadTitle = new Message("This is a testing TITLE", Colors.ORANGE, Fonts.LOADING_TITLE, false);
        Message loadDescription = new Message(loadString, Colors.RED, Fonts.LOADING_DESCRIPTION, false);
        Message loadTip = new Message("This is a random TIP!", Colors.RED, Fonts.LOADING_DESCRIPTION, false);
        Message loadRelease = new Message("Planned game release 2939!", Colors.RED, Fonts.LOADING_DESCRIPTION, false);
        Message loadSingle = new Message("THIS IS A SINGLE MESSAGE! 2o15", Colors.RED, Fonts.LOADING_DESCRIPTION, false);

        MessageList list = new MessageList();
        list.add(loadTitle);
        list.add(loadDescription);
        list.add(loadTip);
        list.add(loadRelease);
        list.add(loadSingle);
        Allign.applyAllignment(g2d, Allignment.BOTTOM_RIGHT, list, loadBox);

        loadBox.testDraw(g2d);
        loadTitle.draw(g2d);
        loadDescription.draw(g2d);
        loadTip.draw(g2d);
        loadRelease.draw(g2d);
        loadSingle.draw(g2d);
    }
}

public class Message 
{   
    private String text;
    private Color color;
    private Font font;
    private int dx, dy;
    private int width, height;
    private Rectancle2D vb; // temp

    public Message(String text, int x, int y, Color color, Font font)
    {
        // set text, color, font, x, y..
    }
    public Rectangle2D obtainFontDimension(Graphics2D g2d)
    {
       if(font == null){ font = Fonts.DEFAULT; }
        g2d.setFont(font);
    
        FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
       GlyphVector gv = g2d.getFont().createGlyphVector(frc, text);
        Rectangle2D vb = gv.getPixelBounds(null, 0, 0);

        this.width = (int)vb.getWidth();
        this.height = (int)vb.getHeight();
        this.gv = gv; // TEMP for bound drawing
    
        return vb;
    }
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
    {
        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.drawString(text, dx, dy);
    
        // TEMP draw bounds
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));
        g2d.draw(gv.getPixelBounds(null, dx, dy));
    }
}

public class Allign
{
    public static enum Allignment
    {
        BOTTOM_RIGHT
        //, etc
    }
    public static void applyAllignment(Graphics2D g2d, Allignment allignment, Object object, Box box)
    {
        Point position = null;
        Point dimension = null;

        if(obj instanceof Message){ // Single Message object }
        else if(obj instanceof Message)
        {
         MessageList messageList = (MessageList) obj;
        
            int listHeight = 0;
            for(Message message : messageList.getList())
            {
                listHeight += message.obtainFontDimension(g2d).getHeight();
            }
            position = new Point(box.x, box.y-listHeight); // offset Y
        
           for(Message message : messageList.getList())
            {
                message.setDrawPosition(allign(allignment, position, new Dimension(message.getWidth(), 0), box, true));
                position.y += message.getHeight();
            }
        }
    }
    private static Point allign(Allignment allignment, Point position, Dimension dimension, Box box, boolean verticalAllign)
    {
        switch(allignment)
        {
            case BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                position = allignRight(position, dimension, box);
                if(!verticalAllign) break;
                position = allignBottom(position, dimension, box);
                break;
            // Rest
        }
    }
    private static Point allignBottom(Point position, Dimension dimension, Box box)
    {
        return new Point(position.x, position.y+box.height-dimension.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the pixel bounds, use FontMetrics.getHeight() to determine how far each line should be from the previous line.  Your text will look better because the lines will be spaced evenly, with some space in between, like all printed material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks David Perez and VGR for the inputs!

I have switched back to the Font metrics, grabbed the height of the string's bounds. However, this only uses the height of the baseline to the highest ascending point. For a proper bottom spacing (like on top) I added the descent integer aswell.

```
public int obtainFontDimension(Graphics2D g2d)
{
    if(font == null){ font = Fonts.DEFAULT; }
    g2d.setFont(font);

    FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics(font);
    Rectangle2D sb = fm.getStringBounds(text, g2d);
    this.width = (int)sb.getWidth();
    this.height = (int)sb.getHeight();
    this.descent = (int)fm.getDescent(); // added
    tempShape = new Rectangle(width, height+descent); // Temp for drawing bounds

    return height;
}
```

Before the allignment begins, I first calculate the total height of all of the Strings in the MessageList. The total height is the height of the String including the descending height.

Then I need to get the offset height for each vertical allignment possibility, which I've added. (TOP, MIDDLE, BOTTOM)

After that, we allign every Message under eachother by adding the height and descent to the offset on every itteration, with vertical allignment disabled this time, or it will reallign every Message horizontally as a single Message object instead as a group of Messages, but it does allow it to allign vertically.

```
if (obj instanceof MessageList)
{
    MessageList messageList = (MessageList) obj;

    int listHeight = 0;
    for(Message message : messageList.getList())
    {
        message.obtainFontDimension(g2d);
        listHeight += message.getHeight()+message.getDescent();
    }

    position = new Point(box.x, box.y);
    Dimension listDimension = new Dimension(0, listHeight);
    if( allignment == Allignment.MIDDLE || allignment == Allignment.MIDDLE_LEFT
    || allignment == Allignment.ABSOLUTE_MIDDLE || allignment == Allignment.MIDDLE_RIGHT)
    {
        position = allign(Allignment.MIDDLE, position, listDimension, box, true);
    }
    else if(allignment == Allignment.BOTTOM || allignment == Allignment.BOTTOM_LEFT
    ||       allignment == Allignment.BOTTOM_CENTER ||  allignment == Allignment.BOTTOM_RIGHT)
    {
        position = allign(Allignment.BOTTOM, position, listDimension, box, true); 
    }
    else
    {
        position = allign(Allignment.TOP, position, listDimension, box, true); 
    }

    for(Message message : messageList.getList())
    {
        position.y += message.getHeight(); // prepare the offset
        message.setDrawPosition(allign(allignment, position, new Dimension(message.getWidth(), 0), box, true));
        position.y += message.getDescent(); // add descending offset for next itteration
    }
}
```

To draw the Messages with the new bounds:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
{
    g2d.setFont(font);
    g2d.setColor(color);
    g2d.drawString(text, dx, dy);

    // Drawing bounds for testing
    g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));
    shape.setLocation(dx, dy-height);
    g2d.draw(tempShape);
}
```

Final result:
[image]

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest a utility class like this?

```
public class TextPrinter {

    public enum VerticalAlign {

        TOP,
        MIDDLE,
        BOTTOM
    }

    public enum HorizontalAlign {

        LEFT,
        CENTER,
        RIGHT
    }

    private Font font;
    private Color color;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private VerticalAlign vAlign = VerticalAlign.TOP;
    private HorizontalAlign hAlign = HorizontalAlign.LEFT;

    public Font getFont() {
        return font;
    }

    public void setFont(Font font) {
        this.font = font;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public VerticalAlign getVerticalAlign() {
        return vAlign;
    }

    public void setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign vAlign) {
        this.vAlign = vAlign;
    }

    public HorizontalAlign getHorizontalAlign() {
        return hAlign;
    }

    public void setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign hAlign) {
        this.hAlign = hAlign;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    private int getOffSetX(int widthText){
        int result = 0;
        if (hAlign == HorizontalAlign.CENTER){
            result = (width - widthText)/2;
        } else if (hAlign == HorizontalAlign.RIGHT){
            result = width - widthText;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private int getOffSetY(int ascent, int descent){
        int result = ascent;
        if (vAlign == VerticalAlign.MIDDLE){
            result = (height + ascent - descent)/2;
        } else if (vAlign == VerticalAlign.BOTTOM){
            result = height - descent;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void print(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.setFont(font);
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);

        int widthText = fm.stringWidth(text);
        g.drawString(text, x + getOffSetX(widthText), y + getOffSetY(fm.getAscent(), fm.getDescent()));
    }
}
```

I use it in my poker game:
https://github.com/dperezcabrera/jpoker

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your opinion! However, this allignment utility can allign a single string. The result of the Allign class for my application must be abled to allign a single Message, a MessageList, an Image, Animation etc. The MessageList must be printed underneath eachother properly.